# c++ polymorphism - accessing inhertied variables

Tags: c++, polymorphism

playersystem and rocketsystem inherit from system, playersystem contains pointer to rocketsystem. im getting an error when i try to access anything that is in system that rocketsystem is supposed to inherit. the runtime error is "expression cannot be evaluated" i set a breakpoint in visual studio, hovered the mouse over the position vector and it said that.

edit: for posterity this is what i was doing, and it turns out it is working, i was just setting th rocketsystem pointer to null for some reason

```
class Vector2D
{
    public:
    float x;
    float y;
    Vector2D(float x_, float y_) :x(x_),y(y_){}
};

class System
{
protected:

    vector<Vector2D> position;

public:

    void addEntity(Vector2D newPos)
    {
        position.push_back(newPos);
    }
};

class projectile :public System
{
public:
    void createRocket(Vector2D pos)
    {
        addEntity(pos);
    }    
};

class player : public System
{
public:
    projectile* rocketSystem;
    void init(projectile* rocketsys){rocketSystem = rocketsys;}
    void fireRocket(Vector2D pos)
    { 
        rocketSystem->createRocket(pos);
    }
};



int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) 
{
    player* PlayerSystem = new player;
    projectile* RocketSystem = new  projectile;

    PlayerSystem->init(RocketSystem);
    PlayerSystem->fireRocket(Vector2D(0,0));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The above is not real code.  Please post real code.

Comment: can you show us the relevant code segments in system?

Comment: Why do you have two `playersystem` class declarations?

Comment: ive edited that, was a mistake

Comment: This is still not valid code. I can see numerous errors and inconsistancies. Put the above in a compiler. Fix it until it provides just your specific error, then post the code and the error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use my psychic powers and guess that the System class doesn't have a `createRocket()` member. Since playersystem has a `System *rocketSystem` and not a `rocketsystem *rocketSystem`, the only functions that can be invoked on the `rocketSystem` member are those declared in the System class. It has to be a `rocketsystem*` if you want to be able to call that function, and the rocketsystem class has to be declared before the `playersystem::fireRocket` function is defined.